# request Google Analytics data from a local server

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I want to write a PHP script that imports web stats data from GA. The script is accessible through a web front end (for triggering the import) and resides on a local server (127.0.0.1).

[image]

As I understood from the documentation is that there are two options for authenticating and using the core API:

1. **API key** - grants only access to statistics
2. **OAuth2** - full authorization

If I understand the mechanics of OAuth2 correctly then this is not an option in my scenario because I cannot specify a callback URL. Hacky solutions come to my mind - like establishing a web profile authentication directly connecting to GA from the browser and then fetching the data by JavaScript and feeding it to the import script - but I would prefer to refrain from such solutions. Also because the browser interaction triggering the import process might be substituted with a cron job in the future.

The API key seems to be exactly what I want but the GET request from the browser fails.

**GET request:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga:[profile ID]
  &start-date=2013-01-01&end-date=2013-01-05
  &metrics=ga:visits
  &key=[the API key]
```

**Response:**

```
{
  error: {
  errors: [
    {
      domain: "global",
      reason: "required",
      message: "Login Required",
      locationType: "header",
      location: "Authorization"
    }
  ],
  code: 401,
  message: "Login Required"
  }
}
```

The URL though should be fine. Except for the key parameter it is the same as the one generated with http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/ which is also working (AOuth2 is used in that case). The API key is fresh.

Then again generating a new API key confronts me with the next inconveniency which is that apparently the key is only valid for a day.

---

So at the end of the day my question is this:

**Is it possible to fetch data in the above described scenario without having to authenticate manually or generate API keys on a daily basis?**

Comment: Take a good look at the [Authorization methods](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/gdataAuthorization#common_oauth) available. There are 2 that should work for you. **Web Server** and **Service Accounts**. With the [Web Server](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) method you still have to go through oAuth, but you have to do it only once. And then after that you get a refresh token that you can use to generate more access tokens when needed without going through oAuth flow again. The [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accou

Comment: Okay, maybe that does the trick. But still I am interested in a full answer also adressing the other mentioned points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already suggested, use this library: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/
but, instead of using oauth, create a **service account** from the api console (just select server application). This will provide you with a client id, an email that identify the service account, and *.p12 file holding the private key.

You then have to add the service account (the email) to your analytics as an admin user in order to get the data you need.

To use the service:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('test');

$client->setAssertionCredentials(
    new Google_AssertionCredentials(
        EMAIL,
        array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
        file_get_contents(PRIVATE_KEY_FILEPATH)
    )
);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');

$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
```

To get some data:

```
$analytics->data_ga->get(PROFILE_ID, $date_from, $date_to, $metrics, $optParams)
```

For the details check api docs. Also, be careful, there is a query cap (unless you pay)

Comment: The thing that prevents me from using this method is **loss of flexibility**. If I have to migrate to another GA account, I need to get new Service Credentials or if I have to fetch data from two different accounts I'll have to use trickery. In the end it's just choice as I have used both!

Comment: I granted the bounty to this answer because (at least superficially) it seems to address my problem more direct than the other answers. I didn't find the time yet to deal more with the project. As soon as I know for sure how to get this done in my case I will mark the answer or write one myself.

Answer (score 2):

I think to get this working, you need to use OAuth but with a slight modification to run it from server. Google calls this auth method "[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)"

As described on that page, you can use a PHP client library to get the authentication done. The client library is located [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2).

An example example on how to use this client library are on the same project's [help pages](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/). Note that you'll have to make some modifications to the code as the comments say to store the token in db and to refresh it regularly.

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_PlusService.php';

// Set your cached access token. Remember to replace $_SESSION with a
// real database or memcached.
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application');
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
$client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
$client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_oauth2_redirect_uri');
$client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_simple_api_key');
$plus = new Google_PlusService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
  $activities = $plus->activities->listActivities('me', 'public');
  print 'Your Activities: <pre>' . print_r($activities, true) . '</pre>';

  // We're not done yet. Remember to update the cached access token.
  // Remember to replace $_SESSION with a real database or memcached.
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

Comment: I don't have a 'insert_your_oauth2_redirect_uri' as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: To accept this answer you would have to explain how to deal with this issue (no redirect URI) or how and why I am wrong with my understanding of the meaning of this URI. PLUS I would prefer a not copy pasted sample code from Google and instead a working example of how to fetch something meaningful like the number of visits for some URL like foo/.

Comment: In your setup, isn't the reqirect uri simply your computer's address. When google redirects the user after authentication, I don't think it validates the URL. And since there is no validation, you can specify http://127.0.0.1/page_that_reads_the_auth_token.

Comment: That's a good point. Seems like I misunderstood the meaning of this URL.

Comment: np. glad to help. @Birla does something very similar in his answer. I don't want to replicate his code but feel free to mark his response as answer if you find his answer easier to understand (he says the same thing as my comment above.)

Comment: does someone know what is the deal with api_key? And why it is not working?

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar setup. The thing that you don't realize is that you can specify a `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` or anything else as an origin and callback URL. You need to setup some web interface on your local server that initiates an OAuth setup for the user with the GA access. Note that this is one time. The callback handler must be something like this:

Note: The libraries used here are the same as the previous answer, the detailed code is in the wrapper.

```
$redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/content/business-intelligence';
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    require_once 'GAPI.php';
    $client = GAPI::init(); //create client instance of Google_Client
    $client->authenticate(); //convert auth code to access token
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $retVal = CF_GAPI::persistToken($token); //save token
    if($retVal)
        $redirect .= "?new_token";
    else
        $redirect .= "?bad_token";
}
header('Location: ' . $redirect); //redirect to bi index
```

Once you have saved the token saved, you must set it in the client before making requests to GA to get your analytics data. Like:

```
try {
    $token = GAPI::readToken(); //read from persistent storage
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $token = FALSE;
}

if($token == FALSE) {
    $logger->crit("Token not set before running cron!");
    echo "Error: Token not set before running cron!";
    exit;
}

$client = GAPI::init(); //instance of Google_Client
$client->setAccessToken($token);
```

The `GAPI::init()` is implemented as follows:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(self::APP_NAME);

$client->setClientId(self::CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(self::CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(self::REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setDeveloperKey(self::DEVELOPER_KEY);

//to specify that the token is stored offline
$client->setAccessType('offline');

//all results will be objects
$client->setUseObjects(true);

//tell that this app will RO from Analytics
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly');

return $client;
```

My mysql table has columns like `id, title, send_to_emails, frequency, dimensions, metrics, filters, profile_id` which completely define each report to the generated from GA. You can play around with them using the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference), [list of metrics & dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) and the [sandbox tester](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) that you already know about.